# How to avoid mutating state when updating a property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that when it is called is passed the initialState and the function to update the state (set through react hooks)

```
const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState("name")

const toggleValue = (initialState, setInitialState) => {
   const myVal = initialState;
   myVal["name"] = "This is a new name"
}
```

My expectations were that reassigning the state to a variable would not cause the state to be mutated when that variable was updated.

However I’m noticing that when I run `toggleValue` initialState is changing to "This is a new name" as well as myVal. Is there a way to avoid mutating the state? My goal is to update a property in the initialState object and then update the state.

Comment: Make a copy of state and than change the value. and use setInitialState to set state

Comment: Since your state is a string, passing it to a variable will make a copy of it. It seems there are multiple problems with your code - could you post the full component (at least the part that uses the state and toggleValue function)

Comment: Hi Nat, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is your state is not an object, it is simple string value,

```
const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState("name")
```

Updating string value is very simple,

```
const toggleValue = (initialState, setInitialState) => { 
   setInitialState("This is a new name") //This will simply change the state
}
```

If your state is an object like,

```
const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState({name:"name"})
```

In that case you can change the state like,

```
const toggleValue = (initialState, setInitialState) => {  
   const myVal = {...initialState}; //This will create a copy
   myVal["name"] = "This is a new name";

   setInitialState(myVal); //This is needed to update the state.
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wokv2i)